# How to fix jqgrid column chooser garbage layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqgrid

Columns list in jqgrid column chooser is displayed in single column and truncated:

[image: Invalid layout]

How to fix this?
Problem occurs in FireFox, Chrome, IE
Page definition is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css" type="text/css" title="ui-theme" />
<link href="ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="ui.multiselect.css" />
<link href="Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-git.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqgrid/plugins/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.contextmenu-fixed2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqGrid.src-multiselect1-deleteandsortpatches.js"></script>
    <script src="json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="erp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var $grid = $("#grid");
    $(function() {
      "use strict";
      $grid.jqGrid({
    ...

    $grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#grid_toppager', {
        onClickButton: function () {
            $(this).jqGrid('columnChooser', {
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can u give live link as like jsfiddle.net

Comment: You have a lot of small errors or very strange things on the posted page (`title` on `<link>`, `var $grid,` before `$(function() {` and so on). Moreover you use unknown versions of jQuery UI (local copy of `jquery-ui-git.js`) combined with *old* CSS from `jquery-ui-1.8.12`. You use some unknown version of jqGrid (`jquery.jqGrid.src-multiselect1-deleteandsortpatches.js`) and so on. **Stackoverflow is not the place where somebody debug *your specific* code for free**. You should simplify your code and post it in the form where it could have some value *for other visitors*.

Comment: One more remark: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` will be ignored for HTML5 (`<!DOCTYPE html>`). You have to set the information in the HTTP headers if you use HTML5.

Comment: @ Rohit Azad I can create private testcase and send a link if somebody is interested. Please let me know is this OK to you.

Comment: @Oleg I'm sorry for that. I edited html code. According to http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html  12.1.4 title is valid attribute for link element. `jquery.jqGrid.src-multiselect1-deleteandsortpatches.js` is based on your patched file with similar name load from your website . jquery-ui-git.js is loaded from jqyery ui git, it has all modules in single file. Git load gives this name.

Comment: @Andrus: I agree that the usage of `title` is possible, but I know some sense to use it only in case of usage `rel="alternate stylesheet"` (see [14.3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#style-external)). In the previous comment I wrote that you don't included any version information about jqGrid and jQuery UI which you used. The information that you get some file from my site help also not. The origin of the problem which you describe can be either incompatibility versions of JavaScripts or CSS which you used or just because one path was just wrong and the file is not loaded.

Comment: @Andrus: In case of suspects of compatibility problems you have to specify *exactly* the versions which you used. An example with jQuery UI: many CSS classes in new jQuery UI, for example from `jquery.ui.menu.css` are heavy changed. Just compare [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.8.20/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css#L24) from jQuery 1.8.20 with new [this one](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/themes/base/jquery.ui.menu.css#L10). So you can't just combine `jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css` with some `jquery-ui-git.js`. You have to use `jquery-ui-git.css`.

Comment: @Oleg: jquery, jquery ui and jqgrid worked OK some time ago. After changes in application this issue occurs. So it looks some application code causes this. Unfortunately it is impossible to find which change caused this, there is no change history. I can create test url to you which shows the issue.

Comment: @Oleg `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` works with `<!DOCTYPE html>` . It only produces html 5 validation error but works OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would get some working demo which uses columnChooser and which work correct and then remove the `ui.multiselect.css` which is required then you would have results which are very close to yours.

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooserWithError.htm) which display

[image]

So I recommend you to verify in Fiddler or Firebug that `ui.multiselect.css` is really correctly loaded in your solution. Probably you should just replace the line

```
<link href="ui.multiselect.css" />
```

with the line

```
<link href="jqgrid/plugins/ui.multiselect.css" />
```

which corresponds to another line which you use

```
<script src="jqgrid/plugins/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are genious. rel attribute was missing as shown in code in question. I added rel attribute by changing line to `<link href="ui.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />` This solves the issue.